# Xcode: sharing the same Bundle ID among multiple people

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git

I'm developing an iOS app with a friend. We both enrolled for the Apple development program as a Single person (we don't have an organization).
We're using git and we'd like to be both able to build the app from our Mac, but I can't compile sinche the Bundle ID is already used by my friend. Is it even possible to be both able to work on the same project without being an organization? What we should do?

Thanks

Comment: For development yes you can do it. By selecting team to "None" while running the application on the device. For publishing and enterprise distribution you cannot use that ID

Comment: with team=none I can't deploy to my iPhone because it still require me to sign, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that only one developer account can register the bundle ID. What Xcode is trying to do is register the bundle ID to your development account (as you can do manually at https://developer.apple.com). Since your friend already did this, you cannot do this as well.

What you can do is either change the value of your bundle ID to a development one (in the end, only one of you can release the app on the App Store) however, this is kind of messy since it'll change the `.xcodeproj` and can be a real conflict mess when using versioning (as I guess you are using).

Another option is to use `.xcconfig` files, and define the bundle ID dynamically in your project. This way you can change your config file locally and just don't push that change. What you do is:

1. Add a new file to your project. Select `Other` under `iOS` and then select `Configuration Settings File`. Save the file and call it `Debug.xcconfig` (or whatever you want). [image: Xcode New File dialog]
2. Add the following row to the file: `BUNDLE_ID = io.example.app`.
3. Select your project in the Project Navigator and then select the project itself under `PROJECT`.
4. Select the `Info` tab and expand both `Debug` and `Release`. For both `Debug` and `Release` select the `Debug` option.
   [image: Xcode project editor]
5. Now open your `Info.plist` file and change the value of `Bundle Identifier` (`CFBundleIdentifier`) to `$(BUNDLE_ID)`.

Now you can change the bundle ID (and a shitload of other Xcode project properties) using the configuration file. You could add one for yourself and your friend as well, each with their own bundle ID.

One problem though when changing the `BundleID` is that services such as APNS won't work. Keep that in mind. If that is important that both should be able to test, then make sure to get an organisation account.

Hope this helped you a little bit!