# Use the same "Bundle ID" for many developers

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer

I work on a project with a friend, can we use the same "bundle id"?. When I clone a project, and try to build it i got the error: "The app identifier "bundle id" cannot be registered to your development team.", then i change bundle id, and it works. But I don't want to do it each time i pull the new code from the server. How do I manage this ?

Comment: You shouldn't change `BundleId` of the app, but to configure development certificates for both developers.

Comment: @LewWinczynski, do you have instruction how to configure this ? I'm just lost with all this provisioning profiles, buidle ids, app ids. I'm new to all of this, and all i want to do is just to be able to build without changing bundle ID, thats all i nedd :)

Comment: Wrote an answer with the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing `bundleId` on both devices, you are changing the signature of the app. Basically saying, you are splitting it into 2 different apps for AppStore. Bundle id should be unique for one app everywhere. As I see you have a problem with different developers accounts that want to use the same bundle id. Just try to add another developer to your **Apple Developer Account** giving an `App Manager` or `Developer` [role](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/), so he/she can work with any reserved bundle id's in your account. I highly recommend you to read [iOS Development Team Administration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH1-SW1)

Comment: I seen this, there is nice picture with "1. create a team" - but i can't find any instructions how to create one, i browsed randomly whole developer portal and cant find a way to create a team :(

Comment: Open your iTunesConnect -> User & Roles, and add another developer into it giving respective role to him/her. Then he/she can get iOS development certificate out of your account for him/her. The rest is intuitive, you will see.

Comment: so I go there, I add another user (send invitation), but i can see that "Apps" dropdown is acctually empty, what i want to share this "bundle id" just to be able to build, dont want to publish any app

Comment: So I added another developer there to "All Apps" but still can't build :)

Comment: Let them create an iOS developer certificate from your account. So they have access to your bundle ids.

Comment: where do I create this, in iTunesConnect or someware else ?

Comment: have a look on this, but do for development: https://hyperpad.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204378199-Create-a-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile

Comment: my friend is an owner of the app, he followed this, and send mi p12 file, I dont know what do to with it now :)

Comment: :( There to many things involved here, apple developer, app store connect, certificates, profiles, xcode settings, keychain etc, etc, im just lost here, what i need is some step by step guide how to get rid of the error "The app identifier "bundle id" cannot be registered to your development team."

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to develop one app from 2 different developer accounts. So, you have to add one dev into another to fix that. I have given you the steps: iTunesConnect -> User & Roles, add another developer, let him request iOS dev certificate in Xcode, and it will work.

Comment: thanks for your patience, just to clarity: we both have buth have paid for a apple developer, but do we need some spacial organisation license or sth ? Question2: i found similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784228/use-the-same-bundle-id-for-many-developers, so now im confused, which solution is possible in my case

Comment: sorry posted wrong link, should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813674/xcode-sharing-the-same-bundle-id-among-multiple-people

Comment: the answer in that link solves the issue temporarily. i've described you the steps, did you even try it?

Comment: Hi i followed the steps, created many certificates (even reach the limit, can generate more today!), recreating my keychain, creating publishing profiles etc, etc, and i also removed the app from the app store connect, and it finally somehow worked, but im not really sure what helped, as i tried so many stuff (i suspect removing app from app store connect helps), but i guess you helped me as well, dziękuje!

Comment: glad to hear that! bardzo proszę ;)

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is, why this guy from the link i sent, had to put that in config ?